# What transaction types should be tested in IPN simulator for PayPal Website Payments Standard?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

On my website, I would like to process the order using the IPNs sent by PayPal.

Before it actually happens, I would like to use the IPN simulator on the PayPal Developer Website (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator) to do some testing.

In the IPN simulator, you can see we have to choose a transaction type to send an IPN test. There are many, some examples are "Express Checkout", "Cart Checkout" and "Web Accept".

My website uses the PayPal "Website Payments Standard" to accept payment but I don't know which transaction type(s) I have to do tests on.

I tried to google but failed to find any detail about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with a Buy Now button then the txn_type you would get would be web_accept.  If you're working with other types of buttons it could be different.

Refer to [PayPal's IPN variables list](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z), specifically the values for txn_type, for more details.